# I want to show contact form 7 on lightbox

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I want to show contact form 7 on lightbox. The theme which ive been using is salient old version. and its not having an custom lightbox feature to show forms on lightbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can perform this with Below code

```
[formlightbox title="Send me a message" text="Contact me"]
  [contact-form-7 id="401" title="Contact form 1"]
[/formlightbox]
```

For this you needs 2 plugins
(1) Contact Form 7
(2) Form Lightbox

you can check this at http://www.myphpmaster.com/form-lightbox-demo/

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: Welcome #nadzhq